# Query on Record - JSON data uploaded to BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

I have this Big Query Record row that I am trying to query and get elements such as the doc_id and doc_type for each row. Since the value is in separate column how would I formulate the query to return the name and the value?.

ex result: 
       `doc_id doc_type
    1  399239 document
    2  999999 document`
 
If I do a query like:

```
select a.value as document_id, from 
`table_name`, UNNEST(jsonPayload.parameters) AS a where a.name = "doc_id"
```

I am able to get the doc_id for all values but can't add other things like doc_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  -- <any other needed fields here>, 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(jsonPayload.parameters) WHERE name = 'doc_id') doc_id,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(jsonPayload.parameters) WHERE name = 'doc_type') doc_type
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
```

with result

```
Row doc_id  doc_type     
1   399239  document     
2   999999  document
```

Or less verbose version with help of SQL UDF

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Extract_Parameter(parameters ANY TYPE, key STRING) AS ((
SELECT value FROM UNNEST(parameters) WHERE name = key
));
SELECT  
  -- <any other needed fields here>, 
  Extract_Parameter(jsonPayload.parameters, 'doc_id') doc_id,
  Extract_Parameter(jsonPayload.parameters, 'doc_type') doc_type
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
```